# A question about ResourceBundleViewResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have configured view resolver to `ResourceBundleViewResolver` and defined properties file as per `basename`. There I configured classes for a view as

```
xyz.class=com.pokuri,view.Xyz
```

But where I return this view from controller I am getting `BeanCreationException`. I tried a lot to identify the issue with it, as it was working fine in earlier example projects. Finally I have changed the mapping to

```
xyz.(class)=com.pokuri,view.Xyz
```

then it start working.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening and not with earlier experimental projects?

Comment: We'll need to see the stack trace of the `BeanCreationException`